# How to customize a Qweb report in order to create a Packing List?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am using odoo8, and I am able to create customized reports using qweb along with creating customized fields and using them in those reports. But I am stuck with a problem.

1. I want to create a Packaging list, it could be under `invoice` or `stock.picking` module.
2. At present I am unable to retrieve the field values of `stock.picking` into reports created under invoice or vise verse. Basically I want to create packing list which will be similar to invoice but without amount and as per the packages made (not as per the `sales_order_line`) along with weight of each package.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the module `stock_picking_invoice_link`. There you have the fields that you need. The link between both models is created when the invoice is validated (if you create the pickings first).

This is the snippet of the fields created in that module:

```python
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking"

    invoice_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='account.invoice',
                                 string='Invoice', readonly=True)

class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    picking_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='stock.picking', inverse_name='invoice_id',
        string='Related Pickings', readonly=True,
        copy=False,
        help="Related pickings "
             "(only when the invoice has been generated from the picking).")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.... With the help of above module i was able to get the product info from the invoice.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you mark the answer as a correct answer please? Thanks